# Print Preview parameters dialogue box not showing all parameter fields - how to fix?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, screen, preview

I'm trying to update a CR file: I have the database SQLserver code pulling all relevant fields, but when I go to see a print-preview, CR pulls up a parameters screen w. only 2 of 4 necessary parameter fields and the report won't preview b/c it's missing crucial data. How do I get to the form to add more fields to the print-preview parameters dialogue box? (e.g. I need from-dept & to-dept added into user-entry-form to pull right data from SQLServer - how get into user-entry-form to add these fields?)

Comment: Can you show code and explain a bit what you've tried so far?

Comment: If a parameter is not referenced in the report it will not show up in the dialogue. Can you be more specific about what happens when it "won't preview"? What happens, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The only time that I've seen this happen is when a parameter is not being used within the report.  I'm not sure which version of CR is being used, but with CRXI if a parameter is used within the report it will show up with a green check mark on it in the field explorer.